# How can I protect my images by claiming with others?

Tags: copyright, copy-protection

I want to post images to my website and social media. But I don't know how will protect my images by to others. I know it can't prevent downloading the images.

But how I can protect or have a proof that I created those images.

Comment: Hi Jows, welcome and thank you for the question. sadly, we cannot give you legal advice. Firstly, because the law on copyright and trademarks is just too different in different markets/countries/parts of the world. Secondly, because of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91116/297831) (while it's not the official SE stance, it kinda is too).

Comment: The only sure fire method... if you don't want an image stolen.. don't put it on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a bullet proof alibi for creation date then submit the file to yourself in registered mail, and keep the letter sealed. This can then be used in court of law.

However this does not protect you from any plagiarism claim. And off course you need to be willing to see their bluff.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you make and where you put it you should use watermarks over the whole image. That would be the safest way to keep people from editing your picture. If you take photos watermark in one way ruins photo so photographers use signatures on them - don't put them in corner or edge because sometimes people will go so far to cut out that part; but don't cover the main part of the photo.

After all that you can't really 100% protect your work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its fine downloading the images but I don't want somebody tell me that my images is not original or I just copied it. Does published date enough to proof its original?

Comment: Probably not. A person can always say  "it's my picture, I just upload it later"...signature on a picture will have you covered about that part. Add you name, or your original site too.